# Spring MVC configuration with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I want to create a web application using Spring MVC framework, so I followed this steps :

1. I download spring-framework-5.1.2.RELEASE-dist.
2. I opened a new project (Web Application) using IntelliJ IDEA.
3. I created a **lib** directory under WEB-INF and I added all JAR file downloaded previously.
4. I created a **view** directory under WEB-INF for all my JSP views
5. I added two XML files: **web.xml** and **spring-demo-servlet.xml**

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

<!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**spring-demo-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pindc.springdemo" />

<!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

When I run my application with GlassFish Server I get this following Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:696)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:662)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:710)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:587)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:526)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1481)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5381)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5626)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
at   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2044)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1690)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:  Failed to instantiate  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1262)
... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:76)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:208)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
... 72 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1621)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1471)



    [2018-11-30T19:30:07.388+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] []    [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)]   [timeMillis: 1543602607388] [levelValue: 900] [[
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1690)
    at    com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
```

Thank's for helping!

Comment: Don't do any of this. Use Maven (or Gradle) instead of manually dealing with dependencies, and for a new application, use Spring Boot instead of legacy container and servlet setup. https://start.spring.io will autogenerate a complete working project for you (and there's an equivalent wizard built into both IDEA and Spring Tool Suite).

Comment: @chrylis Yes, this is a good idea! But I want to learn some foundation of the Spring framework, so I must follow this steps of configuration.

Comment: What you're doing isn't foundational--nobody uses it anymore except in dealing with legacy projects, and *nobody* manages dependencies manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you failed to include jackson-databind jar or the proper version of that jar for your current Spring project.  The latest is 2.9.7, try to build the project with that version.

Please note that the way you are handling the jar dependencies is not the correct way to do this. As @chrylis suggested in the comment, you should be using a build tool either Maven or Gradle for this.

Comment: Thank you for helping,

it seems that GlassFish provide an old version of jackson-databind so I downloaded jackson-databind-2.9.5 JAR file and I added manually to my lib directory. 
It's work fine :D